# office 365 outlook searching current mailbox searches all items

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

I'm using Outlook 2013 for Windows connected to office 365 and I have several mailboxes connected. If I select the search scope in the drop-down box to "Current mailbox", it always searches all the mailboxes.

Is this a known problem. any workaround for it?

Edit: After more investigation, I've discovered that the extra search results apparently from the other mailbox were in the "conflicts" folder, i.e. where there had been a problem syncing the other mailbox, the conflicts seem to appear in my main mailbox, and hence were turning up in the search

Answer (score 0):

I've not come across and was not able to replicate after trying a few different times to do so.  You could go into your account settings and under more settings --> Advanced you can remove the check to "download shared folders".  This should keep Outlook from caching the data in those mailboxes, and search would not then index them locally.

Now when you do a search for cached content if you scroll to the bottom of your results you will see "search complete", however, if you execute a search in one of those shared folders/mailboxes, you should see "server results".  Server searches are sent to the server and executed and this is separate from the local index on cached objects. When there is a mix of content - you usually get the option to "search for more".

Comment: Thanks I will try that. But it seems my problem was actually due to sync conflicts (a perennial problem with outlook when connected to office 365 in my experience)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. The default search function of "Current Mailbox" was returning things in my inbox, sent items, deleted items, etc... .  Just figured out that if you select "Current Folder" instead of "Current Mailbox," you get results only in your inbox (or whichever area of the mailbox you are in).

Answer (score 0):

If you go on Options and then click on the Search tab there are settings there for searching Current Mailbox, Current Folder, etc.